# Telegram mass dm-group adding

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm testing more tools to send mass dm or add members on telegram group/channel. But I have trobles to add and send messages because of telegram. Do you know something about limitations?

I want to know something about telegram limitation and some advise about telegram group/channel scraping